# PHP Calculation using If logic function not working in Value field

Tags: php, forms, html

This is current formula for calculating a value

```
<div class="common-box">
<div class="common-box-left">Approx Value </div>
<div class="common-box-right"><input name="idv" type="text" class="text-box" 
    value="'.(($rows->v_price*3.41)/100) .'" readonly=""/></div>
```

Now when we change it to a very basic calculation purpose with if syntax based on price range, it does not work in

```
<div class="common-box">
<div class="common-box-left">Approx Value </div>
<div class="common-box-right"><input name="idv" type="text" class="text-box" value="'.($a = $this->prodDet->v_price);
  $b=.02889;
  $z=.02307;
  if ($a > 500000){
    $c=$a*$z;
  } else {
    $c=$a*$b;
  }
echo(round($c) . "<br>");.'" readonly=""/>
</div>
```

Could someone help in - what is wrong. 
This may be basic for you - but am learning php - Appreciate your help !!

**Edit**
Below is the complete code

```
     <?php
     define( '_JEXEC', 1);
     $database = &JFactory::getDBO();

  <2 different tables been called>
  after that below:-

      if(isset($_GET["ncvd"])){  
$NewToyVariantDetail=$_GET["ncvd"];
$sql = "SELECT * from toy_newtoy_variants where v_status='1' and v_id='".$NewToyVariantDetail."'";
$database->setQuery($sql);
$rows = $database->loadObject();
$list=' <div class="common-box">
      <div class="common-box-left">Approx Value </div>
<div class="common-box-right"><input name="idv" type="text" class="text-box" 
    value="'.(($rows->v_price*3.41)/100) .'" readonly=""/></div>
      die($list);
     }
   ?>
```

may advise on !!

Comment: Is this part of an echo statement? Please show the full context.

Comment: You are mixing PHP and HTML and you have syntax errors all over the place. You would really be better to just pick up a PHP for beginners tutorial somewhere and go through it.

Comment: Where is the php? Is everything echoed and surrounded by single quotes?

Comment: Hello Barmarm, Newin - thanks for replying. Complete code added. May advise on it. Sure, mark am just on to pho !!

Comment: @Ruchika  $list is missing closing div  and '; at the end. I've posted suggestion on coding based on your previous code and complete code.

Answer (score 1):

**Your code has problem at** :

```
echo(round($c) . "<br>");
```

**Here is the working one**:

```
<?php
$v_price = 500;
echo '
<div class="common-box">
<div class="common-box-left">Approx Value </div>
<div class="common-box-right"><input name="idv" type="text" class="text-box" value="'.($a = $v_price);
  $b=.02889;
  $z=.02307;
  if ($a > 500000){
    $c=$a*$z;
  } else {
    $c=$a*$b;
  }
echo round($c).'" readonly=""/>
</div>';
?>
```

My suggestion would be to write PHP code (as you did calculation) separately , not inside html input code.

**For example**:

```
<?php
$v_price = 500;
$a = $v_price;
$b=.02889;
$z=.02307;
  if ($a > 500000){
    $c=$a*$z;
  } else {
    $c=$a*$b;
  }
$val = round($c);
?>

<div class="common-box">
<div class="common-box-left">Approx Value </div>
<div class="common-box-right"><input name="idv" type="text" class="text-box" value="<?php echo $val;?>" readonly=""/>
</div>
```

**Issues in your updated complete code**:

```
- <div class="common-box">  is not closed
- <div class="common-box-right">  is missing '; at the end


<?php
define( '_JEXEC', 1);
$database = &JFactory::getDBO();

if(isset($_GET["ncvd"])){  
    $NewToyVariantDetail=$_GET["ncvd"];
    $sql = "SELECT * from toy_newtoy_variants where v_status='1' and v_id='".$NewToyVariantDetail."'";
    $database->setQuery($sql);
    $rows = $database->loadObject();
    $list=' <div class="common-box">
    <div class="common-box-left">Approx Value </div>
    <div class="common-box-right"><input name="idv" type="text" class="text-box" 
    value="'.(($rows->v_price*3.41)/100) .'" readonly=""/></div></div>';
    echo $list;
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks, your code seems correct. but somehow its not working in for me. its fetching - ="<?php echo $val;?>" in the resultant output. Am checking at my end - if you have suggestion may let know . thnx

Comment: @Ruchika I think somewhere concatenation going wrong with your php and html code. just debug line by line, you will get it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
value = "<?php echo ($rows->v_price*3.41/100) ?>"
```

Comment: I have a feeling that whole html block at the beginning is actually part of an echo. The OP says the first block of code works.

Comment: @Mike, yeah, looking over the code some more, that makes much more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Inline PHP works better for this ... Although, you might want to make a method a part of the class, that will calculate this for you, so you don't have so much logic put into such a small space.

```
<div class="common-box">
<div class="common-box-left">Approx Value</div>
<div class="common-box-right"><input name="idv" type="text" class="text-box" value="<?=round(($this->prodDet->v_price > 500000) ? $this->prodDet->v_price * 0.02307 : $this->prodDet->v_price * 0.02889));?>" readonly=""/></div>
```

---

This is the direct fix for your problem, but really there are many many issues that are being compounded into this. It's style that we need to talk about.

```
<?php
define('_JEXEC', 1);

$database = &JFactory::getDBO();

if(isset($_GET["ncvd"]))
{
    $NewToyVariantDetail=$_GET["ncvd"];
    $sql = "SELECT * from toy_newtoy_variants where v_status='1' and v_id='" . $NewToyVariantDetail . "'";
    $database->setQuery($sql);
    $rows = $database->loadObject();
    $list ='
        <div class="common-box">
        <div class="common-box-left">Approx Value </div>
        <div class="common-box-right"><input name="idv" type="text" class="text-box" value="'.(($rows->v_price*3.41)/100) .'"readonly=""/></div>';
        die($list);
}
?>
```

---

```
<?php
define('_JEXEC', 1);

$database = &JFactory::getDBO();

if(isset($_GET['ncvd']))
{
    $database->setQuery("SELECT * from toy_newtoy_variants where v_status='1' and v_id='{$_GET['ncvd']}'");
    $rows = $database->loadObject();
    echo '<div class="common-box">';
    echo '  <div class="common-box-left">Approx Value</div>';
    echo '  <div class="common-box-right"><input name="idv" type="text" class="text-box" value="' . ($rows->v_price * 3.41) / 100 . '"readonly=""/></div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

This is better, however, I can't even begin to tell you how bad it is to not filter your inputs. `$_GET['ncvd']` is a ticking timebomb. We need to fix that ...

---

I'm going to take the guess that `v_id` in the database is an int. As such, we use the built in filter functions to clean the input.

```
<?php
define('_JEXEC', 1);

$database = &JFactory::getDBO();

if(isset($_GET['ncvd']))
{
    $nvcd = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'ncvd', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $sql = "SELECT * from toy_newtoy_variants where v_status='1' and v_id='{$ncvd}'";
    $database->setQuery($sql);
    $rows = $database->loadObject();
    echo '<div class="common-box">';
    echo '  <div class="common-box-left">Approx Value</div>';
    echo '  <div class="common-box-right"><input name="idv" type="text" class="text-box" value="' . ($rows->v_price * 3.41) / 100 . '"readonly=""/></div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

This is the version that you should use. I don't understand why you are using `die()`, so you might want end the code execution there. For that, you can simply call [exit](http://php.net/exit) if you must.

Comment: You missed a `$c = ` after your `?`.

Comment: I missed removing the `$c` as in this code example, I'm rounding the mathematical expression wrapped in the ternary operator.

Comment: Hello Mark, Mike - thanks for taking time to debug it. I have added the complete code. Could you see where am i missing bcoz by adding above code it just shows the code in the front end and not the mathematical value out of it. thanks